# Does every object have a universal property?

Tags: category-theory

Let $C$ be a category, and $o\in C$ an object. Does $o$ have a universal property? My first reaction: of course it has:
$$E_o(x):\Leftrightarrow \hom(x,-)\cong\hom(o,-).$$
is the universal property of $o$ in the sense that for any object $a\in C$, if $E_o(a)$, then $a\cong o$ (and of course $E_o(o)$). So this property determines the object $o$ up to isomorphism.

But I just noticed that [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_property) uses another definition of universal property: a *universal property* is given by a functor $F\colon C\to D$ and an object $X\in D$. We say that an object $o\in C$ equipped with an arrow $u\colon X\to F(o)$ satisfies the universal property determined by $(F,X)$ if for any object $o'\in C$ and any morphism $f\colon X\to F(o')$ in $D$ there is a unique morphism $h\colon o\to o'$ such that $F(h)\circ u=f$. Of course, the universal property given by $(F,X)$ pins down $o$ up to isomorphism.

Let's ask the question above again, but this time for this new definition: given any object $o\in C$ is there an arrow $u\colon X\to F(o)$, a functor $F\colon C\to D$, and an object $X\in D$ such that the universal property corresponding to $(F,X)$ is satisfied by $(o,u)$? (Bonus question: is it possible to find such a pair $(F,X)$ for *any* pair $(o,u)$, i.e., if $u$ is given additionally to $o$?)

Comment: The definition of universal property cited includes a morphism $u$ as well as an object $o$; what does it mean to ask if an object alone satisfies a universal property?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Fair enough. Fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Added a bonus question, inspired by your comment. :D

Comment: The bonus question doesn't really make sense - once $u$ is fixed, its domain and codomain are fixed, so you know what $X$ and $F(o)$ are. So then you're pretty constrained in choosing the pair $(F,X)$!

Comment: Ah, you're right, thanks.

Comment: Cf.: https://www.hedonisticlearning.com/posts/styles-of-category-theory.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, any object $X \in \mathcal{C}$ represents the functor $\mathrm{Hom}(X,-) : \mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{Set}$ and therefore has a (trivial) universal property.

Comment: That's what I write in the third sentence. Let's consider the definition of "universal property" taken from wikipedia: how do you choose $D$ and $F$ given $o$?

Comment: $F = \mathrm{Hom}(X,-)$, $D = \mathbf{Set}$, and the universal element is $\mathrm{id}_X$.

Comment: Thanks. One can also consider $D=C$, $F=\mathrm{id}_C$, and $X=o$. Then $(o,\mathrm{id}_o)$ trivially satisfies the universal property corresponding to $(F,X)$.

Comment: It's slightly confusing that you use the variable $X$ for what I call $o$. My $X$ is $\{\bullet\}$ in your setting.